# Exclude Signature images when Exporting attachments to a folder

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments, outlook-2010

I have code to export Outlook attachments to a local folder.

I noticed the little images in the signature are also saved as attachments.

I think excluding the signature images could be done with an If then along the lines of:

```
 For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
 If objAttachments.Item(i).Size > 6000 Then
```

I don't know where to place in my code, especially the End If (after or before the Next).

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub Renamefileandexcludesignature(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim SavePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    SavePath = "C:\Users\Antoine\Documents"
    FileName = "Antoine" & ".csv"
    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
         Atmt.SaveAsFile SavePath & "\" & FileName
    Next
    Set Atmt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're after downloading a specific file type you could check the extension of the attachment (untested, but should work):

```
Public Sub Renamefileandexcludesignature(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim SavePath As String
    Dim FileName As String

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim sExt As String

    SavePath = "C:\Users\Antoine\Documents"
    FileName = "Antoine" & ".csv"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
        sExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(Atmt.FileName)

        Select Case sExt
            Case "jpg", "png"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else
                Atmt.SaveAsFile SavePath & "\" & FileName
        End Select
    Next

    Set Atmt = Nothing
End Sub
```

> But I have little to no knowledge in VBA and don't know where to place
>   in my code, especially the EndIf ( after or before the Next)

These have to go in order -
If you use `IF` and then `FOR` you have to use `NEXT` first to close the `FOR` and then `END IF` to close the `IF`.
If you use `FOR` and then `IF` you have to use `END IF` to close the `IF` before you can use `NEXT` to close the `FOR`.

Hope that made sense.

Comment: Thanks Darren it works seamlessly, however I am looking for something which excludes instead of "including" only csv files.
Is it possible to say something along the lines of "If sExt= "png;jpeg" then don't save them"?

Comment: You can use a `Select Case` statement.  I'll update my code.

Comment: Perfect works clean as a whistle, thanks a lot Darren!

Answer (score 1):

To use `For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1` (*Looping through macro backwards*)

Declare your variables

```
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
```

Now run your loop to save Object item

```
If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
        If objAttachments.Item(i).Size > 6000 Then
           objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile FileName
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Om3r! This looks like what I would need as it would save me the pain of isolating certain formats, however when I enter your code it says: Compile Error: Next without For
Which I don't understand as you have a for 3 lines above...

Comment: @AntoineMyrd looks like I missed `End If` before `Next i`